# How to send input data into Postgres psql.exe?

Tags: c#, postgresql, process

I would like to provide password for user MyUser into psql.exe. Unfortunately all my attempt fail. Please see following code:

```
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql.exe", "-w -t -h localhost -p 5432 -U MyUser -c \"SHOW data_directory\"")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true

        };

        using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = psi })
        {
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Output: {e.Data}");
            };
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Data}");
            };

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Password");
            process.StandardInput.Flush();


            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine($"Exit code: {process.ExitCode}");
        }
```

psql.exe never reads the password from redirected standard input. Thus process hangs on WaitForExit. If I use CreateNoWindow=false than I am able to write password into console window and receive answers in OutputDataReceived, ErrorDataReceived but this is not what I need. I need to run psql.exe without user interaction. Please note that password should not be stored in pgpass.conf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it's a security measure that psql doesn't take passwords from a non-terminal input source.

The *proper* way to do something with a postgreSQL database from any programming language that has good libraries for that (such as C#/.NET) is to simply use a client library to connect to the database and not call an external process.

Comment: It is interesting that I can call pg_ctl.exe and start/stop postgres very easily but if I want to ask database for something there is such big problem. Sure I can create workaround for my need to call psql.exe as following: Insert password into pgpass.conf, restart posgtgres, execute what I need by psql.exe, remove entry from pgpass.conf. But this seems to be little overkill :-)

Comment: @user2126375 that is really not surprising. Starting/stopping a database doesn't alter or give away confidential data. So this is far less critical. Even when I don't share your opinion on something like writing a file being overkill (come on, it's really trivial to implement), don't do that – things will instantly break if two processes try to change the file. Bad idea. Really, really, just use the existing libraries. It's not really harder than calling a program.

Comment: Ok, understand, I will use Npgsql for this one tasks "Where are data for host/port (cluster) stored?" installation process of my app. I tried to chose psql.exe because also other steps in intallation process uses *.exe files from postgres's bin folder (pg_ctl, pg_basebackup, ...). Or is there any other simple way how to get data folder for host/port combination? (I would like to avoid windows registry)

Answer (score 5):

Try it:

```
proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PGPASSWORD"] = "mypass";
```

It works for me.